# Ruby: Can I wrap a class in another class completely transparently?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I need to create a class like the following (the real problem is more complex)

```
class IArray
  attr_reader :array

  # array is a Ruby Array
  def initialize(array)
    @array = array
  end

  def method_missing(...)
    # forwards every call to @array
  end
end
```

Now in my code I want to do

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3]
a2 = IArray.new([4, 5])
a1.concat(a2)
```

The last statement will not work, saying "no implicit convertion of a2 to array".  How does `a1` know that `a2` is not an array?  I´ve implemented `is_a?` and `kind_of?` for `a2` so that it returns `tru`e if asked if it is an array.  What I want is for `a1` to think `a2` is an array and then call any method on `a2` that it needs to do the merge.

I would like the same to happen with any other class, i.e., just wrap it inside a class but let it work as if it were not wrapped.

Comment: Can't you just inherit `IArray` from `Array`? No conversions needed than

Comment: _"I've implemented `is_a?` and `kind_of?` for `a2`"_ – where is that implementation? Besides, your code works just fine for me. `concat` calls `to_ary` which is handled / forwarded by `method_missing`.

Comment: Stefan I´ve implemented _is_a?_ _and kind_of?_ in class IArray and they are never called.  It is true that concat calls to_ary, but the return value of to_ary should be an array and in my case I cannot return @array, I want the call to go through method_missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately, it is not possible in Ruby for one object to simulate another fully. This is an unfortunate limitation, since one object simulating another is one of the cornerstones of OO, and Ruby is an OO language, so this should really be possible.

There are three main reasons why it is impossible:

- **Reference Equality**: Reference Equality ([`BasicObject#equal?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-equal-3F)) breaks simulation, and thus OO. Comparing for Reference Equality allows you to distinguish the simulating object from the simulated object, which should not be possible. You can monkey patch `BasicObject` to remove or replace `equal?`, but that will probably break things left and right.
- **Boolean operators and conditionals**: Boolean operators and conditionals consider only the two singleton objects `nil` and `false` to be *falsy*. There is no way to write your own *falsy* object, therefore, there is no way to simulate `nil` or `false`.
- **Classes instead of Protocols as Types**: some core library and standard library methods as well as some hardcoded internals expect objects to be instances of a specific class to be able to work with them, even though according to OO principles, an object which speaks the same Protocol should have the same Type, regardless of its Class.

You can get quite far, though:

- Very few methods (actually, no methods, I believe) in the core library and standard library check for Reference Equality.
- You will seldom have the requirement to simulate `nil` or `false`.
- Almost always when a particular subroutine requires a particular class, it will provide a level of indirection as an escape hatch and call some conversion method (e.g. the unary prefix ampersand `&` operator calls `to_proc`, the unary prefix asterisk `*` "splat" operator calls `to_a`, `print` calls `to_s`, `Array#[]` calls `to_int`, and so on). Plus, at least for `Numeric`s, there is a defined coercion protocol.

However, in your specific case, you run into one of those cases where it simply doesn't work: while `to_ary` lets you get a long way toward making something that simulates an `Array`, in your case, you need to further keep track of your `IArray`, but of course converting it to an `Array` loses both its identity and its additional behavior. Unfortunately, you're screwed. There's nothing more you can do.

In an ideal OO world, two objects that speak the same protocol should be considered to be of the same type, ergo `Array#concat` shouldn't care about whether or not its argument is an instance of `Array` (or can be converted to one), but rather whether its argument speaks the same protocol as `Array` (or more precisely: speaks the subset of the protocol that `concat` *actually* requires).

I can only speculate why Ruby doesn't follow the OO paradigm in this case: performance. In OO, one object can never know the representation of another object, even if the two objects are of the same type (or the same class). This is the fundamental difference between Object-Oriented Data Abstraction and Data Abstraction based on Abstract Data Types: ADT instances can inspect the representation of other instances of the *same type*, objects can *not* the representation of *any* other object, even if it is of the same type (or class).

However, this means that it is impossible for an operation to inspect the representation of two objects at once (the operation is either a method on a third object, which means that it cannot inspect the representation of either object, or it is a method of one of the two objects, in which case it can inspect its own object's representation but not the other's), and this means that it is impossible to write operations in OO that need access to the representation of two objects at once.

E.g. concatenating two linked lists is O(1), if you have access to the first list's last element's `next` pointer, and the second list's first element's `prev` pointer, but in OO, you can access at most one of the two (unless the two lists explicitly expose a public method that gives access to the two pointers). And concatenating an array to another array requires access to the internal representation of both arrays to be fast, therefore Ruby decides to break OO encapsulation here and requires both objects to be of a class that it knows the internal memory layout of.

This is unfortunate, and not purely OO, but it is a tradeoff that even "hardcore OO" languages like Smalltalk make for some of their core data types. (E.g. numbers, strings, arrays, and booleans.)

In implementations like YARV, JRuby, and others, where significant portions of the core library are implemented with privileged access to the implementation's internals, there is another problem, in that it is very tempting (and there are no ways to prevent this) for core methods to bypass Ruby semantics, for a more convenient implementation. A completely unrelated example: implementing the various complex "overloads" of `Enumerable#inject` in YARV in C, or in JRuby in Java is easy: in YARV, the C function has privileged access to the interpreter internals and can thus inspect the arguments that are passed in ways someone trying to re-implement the method in Ruby cannot, in JRuby, there is some glue magic that allows you to implement those overloaded methods as actual Java overloaded methods, for even more convenience.

Likewise, since all core methods have privileged access to the internal representation of objects in the implementation's GC memory, they will often check the class of an object by directly inspecting its in-memory representation instead of going through `class`, `is_a?`, `kind_of?`, or `instance_of?`.

Comment: Jörg... thanks for your thoughtful answer... much more than I had hoped for!  Can you take a look at my solution bellow and comment on where it can break and what is missing?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SimpleDelegator](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html). I think that will meet your needs.

Comment: Does´t seem to work either for what I need. Maybe a bit more of background will clarify why I need what I need (or someone can come with a completely different idea):  I´m using a java library into which I can "inject" objects.  Since I´m working with JRuby, my array object is just a java object that gets injected into the library.  Once injected, unfortunately I cannot access it as a ruby object, it becomes a wrapped java object in the library.  To call a method on it I need to use the library´s API.  So, I need to capture the call & forward to the wrapped array by means of this API. Clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my (probably incomplete solution to the problem).  In order for this to work, all ruby objects must be "packed" in RBProxyObject as follows:

```
class RBProxyObject

  attr_reader :ruby_obj

  def initialize(ruby_obj)
    @ruby_obj = ruby_obj
  end

  def is_a?(klass)
    @ruby_obj.is_a?(klass)
  end

  def kind_of?(klass)
    @ruby_obj.is_a?(klass)
  end

  def method_missing(symbol, *args, &blk)
    begin
      @ruby_obj.send(symbol, *args, &blk)
    rescue TypeError
      args[0].native(symbol, @ruby_obj, &blk)
    end
  end

  def native(*args)
    method = args.shift
    other = args.shift
    other.send(method, @ruby_obj, *args)
  end

end
```

And now here is how it should be used:

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3]
a2 = [4, 5]

p1 = RBProxyObject.new(a1)
p2 = RBProxyObject.new(a2)


> p p1[0]
  1
> p p2[1]
  5

> p p1.is_a? Array
  true

> p p1.concat(p2)
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What other methods should be added to this class and where can it break?  Thanks...